# Difference in key/value subjects in Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm a newbie in schema registry in Kafka, but I cannot realize what's the difference between kafka-value and kafka-key in schema registry?
I registered a new topic: test
Now, if I make a request to /subjects I have:

- test
- test-value
  So my question:

1. what the difference between them? If I wanted to update schema I have to update key or value?
2. why I need key with schema and different versions and value with a different version?
3. why in control center key for shcema is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka message can have headers, key, payload... the key  and the payload (value) can have schemas, they are maintained in different "subject" the topic-key is for schemas for the key, the topic-value is for the schemas of the payload

Comment: hmm. And what if I use avro schema? what is the key in this?

Comment: Same... the key and value (payload) can have different types, you might be not using / producing key to the records at all... it is valid use case... think of key:value pairs , the key can be string while the value be AVRO or vice-versa.